# Web scraping from html that gets added on button press

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, web-crawler

Im trying to scrape data from a page that has a huge table, the table shows 100 entries as default. There is a select/option at the bottom that lets you change the entries to 200 or All.

How do I set the selecter to All before scraping the table as I want to scrape from all entries, not just the first 100.

Im using node.js/JavaScript to scrape from the page.

Comment: What does the website look like? How is the data in the table being added? Especially, how are the next entries appended? And what did you try so far?

Comment: Is there a way to check using the developer console what the select element calls when it is changed? Sorry im new to this type of development

Comment: Well, the scraping should be successful if the entries are just hidden by css. So, the content might be loaded via AJAX calls. Is there a delay or even a page reload, when you change the number of entries? To see, if there is an AJAX request going on, you could check the "Network" tab on the developer console (if you use Chrome, I don't know the name on other browsers).

Comment: https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2017/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/-1/sort_by/rank_label/sort_order/asc/cols/scores

This is the page, the url changes to -1 just after length when you click all, but if you paste that url in it only shows 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table, that is displayed on the link you provided in the comments gets filled by a JSON file. You can acces the JSON-File directly under [this path](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/datatables_json/the_wur_datatables-panel_pane_1-0f27df84b2d81993eaa509ab222661a1.json).

There is the data you needed, provided in a clean and easy JSON file. You can parse it and get all information you need.

Comment: How did you get that? I have other sites that are similar and i think it could be helpful to know. Is the table filled after page load, as the html that i pull down from my web scraper doesnt have anything in the table body

Comment: I just opened the developent tools (using chrome) and switched to the network tab. After reloading the page, you can see all network traffic, that is going on. If you filter to only show XHR requests, it shows only one entry. By rightclicking and "open in new tab" you see the page i just sent you.

Comment: Thank You, the other site is very similar